# The attributes in my body tag is not working if I put the css in a separate file

Tags: html, css

This is for an assignment and it is required of me to save the css in a separate file. If I keep them in the same file, the website works perfectly, but if I save them separately, the attributes in 'body' do not show at all.

my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Jake's Coffee Shop</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1> Jake's Coffee Shop </h1>

<div class="links">
    links
</div>


<div class="content">

    <div class="para">
        text

    </div> 

</div>

<div class="footer">

    <p> Copyright © 2011 Jake's Coffee House<br></p>

</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

my css code:

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-color:#ffffcc;       
    font-family:verdana;        
}

...


</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

The linked CSS file should not have the  tags around it. It should just be the css alone. Also make sure the href in your link correct points to the style sheet.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers here, consider using `./styles.css` for your `href`

Comment: depends on where his css is located ;) if the css is in the same location its good enough what he got in his code ;)

Comment: Not necessarily, I've had this same issue before and adding `./` in front of the path fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `<style>` tag from the css file.

Answer (score 1):

remove `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>` from your css content...

and also the three dots like `...`

your css should only includes this code here:

```
body {
    background-color:#ffffcc;       
    font-family:verdana;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either place your `<style>` in `<head>` (below snippet) or delete `<style`> tags and import stylesheet to head using tag:

#### Importing styles from separate file

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Where `style.css` is name with path to your styles file.

You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).

#### Placing styles in `<head>`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Jake's Coffee Shop</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #ffffcc;
      font-family: verdana;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Jake's Coffee Shop </h1>
  <div class="links">
    links
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="para">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p> Copyright © 2011 Jake's Coffee House<br></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```